# Check list for part of value and return whole value

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have a master list of ID numbers and another list of partial ID numbers. I need to check if the partial ID number is in the master list. If so, I need to return the whole ID number into a new list. What I have:

```
master_list = ['20000-K-A', '20000-K-B', '20000-K-C', '30000-R-X', '30000-R-V', '30000-R-F']

partial_list = [20000, 40000, 500000]

new_list =[]

for x in partial_list:
  if x in master_list:
    new_list.append(x)

print(new_list)
```

Now this only works if the partial ID number is EXACTLY what is in the master list. How do I return the value from the master list so that I can add it to the new list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a lookup dictionary first from `master_list` (note that the `master_list` is a list of strings while `partial_list` is a list of integers, so we need to cast the prefix to int):

```
d = {}
for item in master_list:
    k, _ = item.split('-', maxsplit=1)
    d.setdefault(int(k), []).append(item)
```

which looks like:

```
{20000: ['20000-K-A', '20000-K-B', '20000-K-C'], 
 30000: ['30000-R-X', '30000-R-V', '30000-R-F']}
```

Then iterate over `partial_list` to get the partially matching Ids:

```
new_list =[]
for x in partial_list:
    new_list.extend(d.get(x, []))
```

Output:

```
['20000-K-A', '20000-K-B', '20000-K-C']
```

Comment: This works really well. Thank you. One question: if I wanted to take the line ` k, _ = item.split('-', maxsplit=1)` and instead of splitting by the first dash, split it by the second, would it be possible?

Comment: @wayoh22 you could split on dash and join the first two items.